# Running python script on command line fails

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to run a python script on my Windows 10 Computer. The structure of the directory looks as follows

```
MyProject
   - src
      - main.py
      __init__.py

      - features
          - featureExtraction.py
          - __init__.py
```

The main folder is "MyProject". In "MyProject" is a subfolder called "src". In "src" the files "main.py" and "**init**.py" as well as the folder "features" exists. In the folder "features" there are the files "featureExtraction.py" and "**init**.py".

In "main.py" I have the following import:

```
import src.features.featureExtraction
```

When I run main.py within pycharm everything works, but when I start the script on the command line using "python main.py" (beeing in the src folder), then I'm getting an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'".

Why does this happen?

Comment: Try: `import features.featureExtraction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you executed `import src.features.featureExtraction` while in the `src` folder. That import makes sense only while you are in the parent `MyProject` folder.

In pycharm prefs, search for Project Structure and notice the content root (MyProject) that it is using. That explains the different behavior you saw from IDE and from command line.

Comment: Ok so I have to use import features.featureExtraction. But how can I make it run both in the IDE and command line? I think the IDE needs then import src.features.featureExtraction

Comment: In pycharm prefs, search for Project Structure, and right click to add source folders as appropriate. This is similar to changing sys.path or PYTHONPATH.